# Check if all elements in one array are contained in another

Tags: java, arrays

Given two lists of numbers(called listA and listB),I need to write a Java method
which returns a boolean value to state whether or not all the elements in
listA are contained in listB.

I can't quite get my code to work as it always seems to be returning false.

```
public static boolean containsAll( int[] listA, int[] listB)
    {
        boolean containsAll = true;
        int ctr1 = 0, ctr2 = 0;

        while(ctr1 < listA.length && containsAll)
        {
            ctr2 = 0;
            while(ctr2<listB.length && containsAll)
            {
                if(listA[ctr1] != listB[ctr2])
                    containsAll = false;
                ctr2++;
            }
            ctr1++;
        }
        return containsAll;
    }

    public static void testContainsAll()
    {
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter size of  first array");
        int array1[] = new int[input1.nextInt()];

        System.out.println("Enter number of ints required");
        for(int i=0; i<array1.length; i++)
        {
            array1[i] = input1.nextInt();
        }

        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter size of  second array");
        int array2[] = new int[input2.nextInt()];

        System.out.println("Enter number of ints required");
        for(int i=0; i<array2.length; i++)
        {
            array2[i] = input2.nextInt();
        }

        boolean containsAll = containsAll(array1,array2);
        if(containsAll == true)
            System.out.print("listB contains all elements of listA");
        else
            System.out.print("listB doesn't contain all elements of listA");
    }
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in your debugger? What did you find?

Comment: You can simply transform each array into a HashSet and check their intersection.

Comment: @JacobG. Not simply.

Comment: @shmosel Why not?  `new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(array)).retainAll(otherSet);`

Comment: @JacobG. Try it and let me know.

Comment: As a basic learning exercise in debugging you need to write out a short testcase _on paper_, say `listA={1,2,3}` and `listB={1,2,3,4,5}`. Then _manually_ step through your code, keeping track of what's happening.  You'll figure it out pretty quickly.

Comment: @shmosel Just posted my answer, forgot I can't wrap primitive arrays so used a Stream instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set `containsAll` to false as soon as you find a different element. It's only false if *no* elements match, which you don't know until the inner loop completes. Here's a simple implementation:

```
public static boolean containsAll(int[] listA, int[] listB) {
    outer:
    for (int a : listA) {
        for (int b : listB) {
            if (a == b) {
                continue outer;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Or if you dislike gotos:

```
public static boolean containsAll(int[] listA, int[] listB) {
    for (int a : listA) {
        if (!contains(listB, a)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private static boolean contains(int[] list, int i) {
    for (int e : list) {
        if (e == i) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks shmosel didn't realise i was setting containsAll to false in the inner loop so that it wasn't really checking against all the elements in the second array

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a HashSet from the int[] and then check if the array contains all elements by calling `containsAll`

```
public static boolean containsAll(int[] listA, int[] listB){
       Set<Integer> a = Arrays.stream(listA).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
       Set<Integer> b = Arrays.stream(listB).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
        return a.containsAll(b);
        }
```

Comment: You can't wrap a primitive array in `Arrays.asList()`.

Comment: Why would you collect to a list and then copy to a set?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to go about this is to convert each array into a Set, and then use Set#retainAll to determine equality.

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] b = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

Set<Integer> A = Arrays.stream(a).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
Set<Integer> B = Arrays.stream(b).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());

System.out.println(B.containsAll(A));
```

This will print `true` if every element in A is in B, otherwise `false`.

Thanks to shmosel for recommending `Set#containsAll`!

Comment: Boxing into temporary collections seems a little excessive to me. Btw you can just call `containsAll()`.

Comment: True, `containsAll()` would be simpler.  I'll edit my post.  However I don't think OP will have to deal with a large amount of elements due to using a Scanner for user-input to populate each array, so boxing shouldn't be an issue.